# jQuery not working when logged in as admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to do an auto cart update whenever a customer modify the quantity of an item. It's already working when I'm NOT logged in, but strangely when I'm logged in, this particular script won't work.

jQuery:

```
    var timeout;
    jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', 'input.qty', function(){ 
            if(typeof timeout !== undefined) clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
        }, 1500);
    });
```

Child theme's functions:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dp_cart_refresh_update_qty' ); 
function dp_cart_refresh_update_qty() { 
    if (is_cart()) { 
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'cart_auto_refresh',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/cart_auto_refresh.js',
            array('jquery')
        );
    } 
}
```

No error console output when this happened. It just doesn't do anything, not even triggered. I've tried putting console.log on some parts the code, nothing.

I've added several others jQuery with this exact method, and all of them work normally, for admin and logged out users.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

I've checked the "update_cart" button, it's there on the cart page, although I set it to display:none

```
<input class="btn btn-alternative" name="update_cart" value="Update Shopping Cart" type="submit">
```

Comment: Open the source code of your frontend page and check if cart_auto_refresh.js is there.

Comment: @IvnH Yup, it's there..

Comment: Can you update the question, so we can see a full content of cart_auto_refresh.js ?

Comment: @IvnH The first code snippet on my question is the full content of cart_auto_refresh.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the jQuery code like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var timeout;
    jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', 'input.qty', function() { 

        if (typeof timeout !== undefined) 
            clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
        }, 1500);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot! One more question, why does this code works when I'm logged out?

Comment: In the inspector, check if event handler assigned when you logged out?

Comment: Yup, it's assigned to div.woocommerce, when I'm logged in and when I'm logged out.

Comment: Ah I've just reverted back to the original code, the one not working doesn't have event handler assigned. While the one working is using breeze.js, I assume it's only working because it's in the cache?

Comment: Yes, it might be a cache issue.